# Flume 1.6 kafka source

Tags: flume-ng

- kafka_2.10-0.8.2.0
- flume 1.6

This is my flume configuration:

```
    a1.sources = r1
    a1.sinks = k1
    a1.channels = c1

    a1.sources.r1.type = org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource
    a1.sources.r1.zookeeperConnect = a2:3181
    a1.sources.r1.topic = testk
    a1.sources.r1.batchSize = 5
    a1.sources.r1.channels = c1

    a1.sinks.k1.type = logger

    a1.channels.c1.type = memory
    a1.channels.c1.capacity = 1000
    a1.channels.c1.transactionCapacity = 100

    a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
    a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

I'm receiving the following error:

```
2015-03-05 20:26:33,675 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [ERROR - org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:253)] Unable to start PollableSourceRunner: { source:org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource{name:r1,state:IDLE} counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } } - Exception follows. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/zookeeper/Watcher at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449) at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.connectZk(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:156) at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:114) at kafka.javaapi.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:65) at kafka.javaapi.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector.(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:67) at kafka.consumer.Consumer$.createJavaConsumerConnector(ConsumerConnector.scala:100) at kafka.consumer.Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(ConsumerConnector.scala) at org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSourceUtil.getConsumer(KafkaSourceUtil.java:47) at org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource.start(KafkaSource.java:200) at org.apache.flume.source.PollableSourceRunner.start(PollableSourceRunner.java:74) at org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:251) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.Watcher at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ... 29 more 2015-03-05 20:26:33,679 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [ERROR - org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor$MonitorRunnable.run(LifecycleSupervisor.java:264)] Unsuccessful attempt to shutdown component: {} due to missing dependencies. Please shutdown the agentor disable this component, or the agent will bein an undefined state.
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Hi @satuphat, welcome to StackOverflow. It's unclear what you're asking in your question. Could you edit your question so that it's a bit clearer? You might want to read the [guide to formatting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to help you correctly format your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this error by providing the flume-env.sh file with the path to a zookeeper jar. 
After that just restart your agent and you should see the info from your Kafka topic flowing.

```
FLUME_CLASSPATH="/path/to/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.3.1/share/hadoop/common/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh5.3.1.jar"
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!!.  I didn't realized that it needed the jar in the flume client.